# Golang: weird syntax in environmentasmap.go

Tags: function, go

I've stumbled upon [this](https://gist.github.com/naveensrinivasan/5846791) piece of code  and two variables & function declarations from it look weird as hell:

```
getenvironment := func(data []string, getkeyval func(item string) (key, val string)) map[string]string {...}
```

```
environment := getenvironment(os.Environ(), func(item string) (key, val string) {
```

I understand what the code does in general, but these two lines just freak me out. Is it even okay to write like this? How do these unnamed (`func(item string)`) and empty (`getkeyval`) functions work?

Answer (score 1):

`getenvironment` is a function variable that is a function that takes a `[]string`, and another function `getkeyval`. The `getkeyval` function is expected to get a `string` item, and return `key,val` string values. The `getenvironment` function returns a map.

The second snippet calls that function, passing an anonymous function for `getkeyval`.

Answer (score 1):

The first line **assigns** a function literal to a variable called `getenvironment`. The first parameter of a call to that function needs to be of type `[]string`. The second parameter needs to be of type `func(string) (string, string)`.

The second line **calls** the function literal assigned to `getenvironment`, where the value returned by `os.Environ()` is of type `[]string` and

```golang
func(item string) (key, val string) {
    splits := strings.Split(item, "=")
    key = splits[0]
    val = splits[1]
    return
}
```

is of type `func(string) (string, string)`.

A thing to not get thrown off by here is the names of the parameters and return values. These don't affect a function's signature, and purely serve the purpose of documentation/code readability.

The whole logic could be collapsed into a single function declaration like so:

```golang
func getenvironment(data []string) map[string]string {
    items := make(map[string]string)
    for _, item := range data {
        splits := strings.Split(item, "=")
        key := splits[0]
        val := splits[1]
        items[key] = val
    }
    return items
}
```